# Configure Wifi connection (802.1x EAP) from ionic 5 App

Tags: ionic-framework, configuration, wifi

I am building an Ionic 5 app and need to configure and connect to a new wifi network with security type (802.1xEAP) , so basically all the info needed as identity and password are being sent from the App programmatically .

I have tried hotspot/ Wifiwizard2 plugins without any success because of limitations.

Would love to know if any plugin supports such operation or any workaround is very welcomed.

The following are my ionic info if needed :

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.0 (C:\Users\gmatta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI   : 2.1.2
   @capacitor/core : 2.1.2

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (1 plugins total)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.11.0
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

NodeJS : v12.18.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.4
   OS     : Windows 10

Comment: What are the limitations that you have found with those solutions? What is the operation that you are looking for?

Comment: The limitations  where that i can only create wifi with WEP/ WPA security types .  I wanted to create an 802.1xEAP as security type

Comment: I am facing same problem 802.1xEAP as security